# Reproduce list of base64 encoding audios one by one

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of Base64 encoded audios that I'm trying to reproduce one by one. The issue is that all elements are being reproduced at once. The following is my code.

You can download the [audios.json](https://gist.github.com/DiracSpace/6623dcb1a1ab4bf9cf07dff5409d5363)

```
  async sayChunks() {
    const ttsResponses = await this.getTestJson();
    console.log("ttsResponses:", ttsResponses);
    for (const ttsResponse of ttsResponses) 
    {
      console.log("playing audio chunk");
      const encodedAudio = ttsResponse.base64Audio.replace(/['"]+/g, '')
      await this.playAudio(encodedAudio);
      console.log("stopped playing audio chunk");
    }
  }

  async playAudio(encodedAudio: string) {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
      const audio = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64," + encodedAudio);
      audio.onended = () => resolve();
      audio.play();
    })
  }
```

Comment: Paste your code as text instead of picture.

Comment: Sorry @RickyMo, that was just another solution I was trying out. Added the fixes now

Comment: This site requires that questions asking for debugging help ("Why isn't this code working?") must include a [mre] that demonstrates the issue. Please provide that MRE, along with the sample JSON content.

Comment: @KenWhite, just added that. sorry for pasting a picture. I also added the JSON file with the required information for the MRE

Comment: A link to an off-site JSON file is not acceptable. We don't leave this site to go get information needed for your post. All relevant information has to be here, in the question itself. For more information, see the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Comment: So very sorry, @KenWhite, I thought using gist.github was an acceptable domain and was not aware of the guidelines. I will read them for future posts. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write an `async` function which return a `Promise`, you have to `await` the `Promise` when returning. Or you can directly return the `Promise` without making the function `async`.

Either:

```
  async playAudio(encodedAudio: string) {
    return await new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
      const audio = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64," + encodedAudio);
      audio.onended = () => resolve();
      audio.play();
    })
  }
```

Or simply:

```
  playAudio(encodedAudio: string) {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
      const audio = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64," + encodedAudio);
      audio.onended = () => resolve();
      audio.play();
    })
  }
```

Comment: You can spot the problem if you have the habit of properly declaring the function return type, fully taking advantage of typescript. When you write `async playAudio(encodedAudio: string) {return new Promise<void>(...);}`, the return type is actually `Promise<Promise<void>>`, while the return type of the fixed version is `Promise<void>`.